# How to call a method from a Django Class Model to a Django field?

Tags: django, python-3.x, django-models

I have created the following Django Model and I am trying to initialize one field - `points` - with the total number of instances of that same model, that is:

```
class Task(models.Model):
    DEFAULT_VALUE     = 5
    description       = models.CharField(max_length=60)
    points            = self.total() * DEFAULT_VALUE
    STATUS            = (('A', 'Active'), ('C', 'Cancelled'), ('D', 'Done'))
    status            = models.CharField(max_length=1, choices=STATUS, default='A')

    def total(self):
        count_active = len(Task.objects.filter(status='A'))
        return count_active
```

In the `python manage.py shell` I can create two instances of `Task` and I can determine the total number of the instances that have been created with `len(Task.objects.filter(status='A')))`, however, when I try to implement this same code into a function then I encounter that `self` is an unresolved reference. What did I miss?

Comment: what do you want achieve by this line: `points = self.total() * DEFAULT_VALUE`? You can't use `self` in class attributes.

Comment: By using `points = self.total() * DEFAULT_VALUE`, I am initializing the Django field of every new Task instance to a value that varies according to the number of each new Task instance.

Comment: I don't understand. Where are those instanced fields? I don't see any object creation.

Comment: So, you want store in `points` field number of active tasks at the time of creation new Task instance? Example: 1)you create 4 active tasks 2)now you creating fifth task and points of this task equal `20` (count of active tasks is 4 and `DEFAULT_VALUE` is 5). Is this your goal? What will happend if number of active task will decrease later?

Comment: @ShilNevado, I don't want to create the object. I want to call the method from inside of the class without creating an object.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use class method:

```
class Task(models.Model):
    ...
    @classmethod
    def total(cls, status=None):
        return cls.objects.filter(status=status).count()
```

Usage:

```
Task.total('A')
```

Comment: One drawback of this method is User can't edit/change the value **`points`** field

Answer (score 7):

**Solution:** Write a ***function***, which provides default value to the field

```
from django.apps import apps


def get_points():
    Task = apps.get_model(app_label='your_app_name', model_name='Task')
    return Task.objects.filter(status='A').count() * Task.DEFAULT_VALUE


class Task(models.Model):
    DEFAULT_VALUE = 5
    STATUS = (('A', 'Active'), ('C', 'Cancelled'), ('D', 'Done'))
    description = models.CharField(max_length=60)
    points = models.IntegerField(null=True, blank=True, default=get_points)
    status = models.CharField(max_length=1, choices=STATUS, default='A')
```

**What I've done here??**
I've created a **`IntegerField`** to store the `point`s data with a ***`default`*** parameter, which is a ***`callable default function`***.

Answer (score 3):

```
class Task(models.Model):
    ...
    @staticmethod
    def total():
        return len(Task.objects.filter(status='A'))
```

And in shell you can call this method from class or instance:
`Task.total()` or `task = Task(*some_arguments); task.total()`

Comment: I implemented this method but when I try to call it in a Django field I encounter the same error `unresolved reference`

Comment: `unresilved reference` of what? There is no `self` in this method.

Answer (score 0):

How do you call the function? I have many properties with the same estructure and all works. But you have to instance the Task. For example I have this code:

```
@property
def is_expired(self):
    now = timezone.now()
    td = now - self.creation_time
    _seconds = td.total_seconds()
    validity_last = _seconds / 3600
    if validity_last < self.validity_minutes:
        return False
    return True
```

To call it I have to make an instance of the model:

```
obj = ModelObject.objects.get(pk=1)
obj.is_expired()
```

Yours have the same structure so the code seems ok.

Comment: I see that in your code you make an instance of the class but in my case I would have to make an instance of the class inside of the class which doesn't do sense :(

Comment: Then you have to use @Jonhy Beebop answer. I tried it and works. Dunno why u still have unresolved reference. It must be in other piece of code.